# Export filtered JTable data to text file

Tags: java, swing, filter, jtable, export-to-text

I am making a java app where user can search for data in the JTable. I have used filters to let user search content from the JTable. I also intend on exporting the filtered data to a text file. But when I do, it exports the whole table data instead of just the searched data. This is what i have tried:

```
        DefaultTableModel Model = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel(); 
        TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> tr = new TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel>(Model);
        table.setRowSorter(tr);

        if(srchop.getSelectedItem().toString() == "Name Of Publication") {
            
            tr.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(nameOfPub.getText().trim().toLowerCase()));
            
        }else if() {
            //code for search through other jtextfields
        }else{}
    
        table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
        table.setRowSorter(tr);
        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        fileChooser.setDialogTitle("Export the data to");
        fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
        fileChooser.addChoosableFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("XML Documents","xml"));
        fileChooser.addChoosableFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("Text Files","txt"));
        fileChooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(true);
        int userSelection = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(this);
        if(userSelection == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
                File fileToSave = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                String ftsEx = fileToSave.getPath();
                int index = ftsEx.lastIndexOf('.');
                String ext = ftsEx.substring(index + 1);                    
                try {
                    
                    if(ext.equals("txt")) {
                    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fileToSave);
                    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                    for (int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < model.getColumnCount(); j++) {
                            bw.write(model.getValueAt(i, j).toString()+" ");
                        }
                        bw.newLine();                    
                        }
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "EXPORT SUCCESSFUL","INFORMATION",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    bw.close();
                    fw.close();
                    }else if(ext.equals("xml")) {
                        
                        ////XML export code
                
        }
```

Is there any way I can store the filtered data to some other jtable and then use that to print into the file. Or any other way it can be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to my problem was to use 'table' instead of 'model'. Model stores all JTable data but table stores only the data currently displayed in the JTable.